# R: Adding Space between X-axis tick Marks in Manhattan Plot?

Tags: r, plot, axis, scatter-plot

I'm currently using the qqman R package to create Manhattan plot:

```
library(qqman)
manhattan(gWasResults,cex.axis = 0.5)
```

[image]

But I want to change all of the colors in each chromosome to black like this:

```
manhattan(gWasResults,col = c("black","black"),cex.axis = 0.5)
```

[image]

If I want to add spacing between each chromosome so that you can distinguish which column of data/ or datapoints belongs to which chromosome, is there a specific plot argument I can specify in the Manhattan module to do this (see for example image below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `ggplot2`. Actually, the example graph that you gave for a desired output seems created with `ggplot2`.

Here are two solutions:

## a) Using jittering - `geom_jitter`

```
library(qqman)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = gwasResults,
       aes(x = as.factor(CHR),
           y = -log10(P))) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) + # adjusting width, impacts the spacing
  labs(x = "CHR") +
  # remove space between plot area and x axis
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.1))
```

[image]

## b) Using faceting - `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(data = gwasResults,
       aes(x = BP, 
           y = -log10(P))) +
  geom_point() +
  # remove space between plot area and x axis
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.1)) +
  # facet by CHR
  facet_grid(cols = vars(CHR),
             space = "free_x",
             scales = "free_x",
             switch = "x") +
  labs(x = "CHR") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "cm") # adjust spacing between facets
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to simply add vertical lines in the "a) Using jittering - geom_jitter" example? E.g. to get the range of the "jitter" and store that in an object to enclose the points plotted between lines?

Comment: Hi @M.Beausoleil Thanks for your comment. I am a bit overbooked at the moment so I advise you to open a new question as others might have more time currently and nice solutions.